# How to change the hostname in a redirect url to keycloak?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-connect

Suppose the application and keycloak are installed on the same machine. If the user with the browser is also on that machine, localhost is used everywhere and everything works.

But now the user is on another machine, and tries to access a page, which requires a login via keycloak,

```
http://applandkeycloakmachine:8080/resource
```

Then there follows a redirect:

```
http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=c...
```

But on the machine where the user is is no process on port 9080. So how can you change the hostname in the redirect url?

Comment: What keycloak url are you using in your application?